# How to get Date component in LINQ?

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I'm trying to reference only the date component on EntityFramework DateTime properties.  I'm using the following:

```
myEntity.Table1.Where(t1 => t1.SomeDateField.Date == anObject.DateTime.Date)
```

but get this error:

The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.  Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

I've seen suggestions to use:

```
EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateTimeStart)
```

That didn't work.  I don't have any DateTimeStart property either.

I have a date in the database, t1.SomeDateField.Date, of '2013-11-11 00:00:00.0000'.

I'm trying to match it against, anObject.DateTime.Date, '11/11/2013 12:00:00 AM'.

Any ideas how I can match a database date-only against an object date-only?

I'm using .NET 4.

Comment: What version of EntityFramework are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`TruncateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is the way to go here. Try following:

```
myEntity.Table1.Where(t1 => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(t1.SomeDateField) == anObject.DateTime.Date)
```